# Errors of aio_write

Tags: c, linux, aio

I'm rewriting a `write` to `aio_write` so I can deal with timeouts (and I don't want to bother with `select`). One thing that I don't understand from the man pages is how can the `aio_write` fail.

For `write` I'm mostly interested in partial writes and `EINTR`. Can `aio_write` (`aio_error` to be precise) return `EINTR` or do partial write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One thing that I don't understand from the man pages is how can the
>   aio_write fail.

`aio_write(3)` per se rarely fails, only if you give it bad data or the system is out of resources.

`aio_error(3)`, on the other hand, is what you use to check the status of queued (or perhaps already completed) operations.

So, yes, `aio_error(3)` can return `EINTR` under the same conditions that `write(2)` would return it: if a signal was caught before writing has started, and the signal handler returned (and the signal handler was not set up with the `SA_RESTART` flag in the `sa_flags` field of `struct sigaction`, otherwise the syscall would be automatically restarted and you wouldn't see `EINTR`).

As for partial writes, it can also happen - again, under the same conditions as it would for `write(2)` - but you can't check this from the return value of `aio_error(3)`. The usual flow is as follows:

- You call `aio_error(3)` to see if the operation is in progress or is completed (or was canceled). If it returns anything other than 0, then either there was an error, it's in progress, or it was canceled. So, no writes actually happened and you cannot call `aio_return(3)`. If it's in progress, either do something else and try again later, or use `aio_suspend(3)` to wait for it to complete.
- If `aio_error(3)` returns 0, then it means that the request completed successfully. Partial writes are interpreted as success. So then you call `aio_return(3)` to get the actual return value from the underlying `write(2)` that took place: this is when you can check for partial writes.

Note that partial writes are not necessarily an error; that's why `aio_error(3)` doesn't treat them like so. For example, a pipe write channel with `O_NONBLOCK` enabled may write less bytes than requested if there isn't enough capacity to write all of them.

Comment: How would I go about implementing a resume for a partial write? Does the `aio_error` modify the `aio_nbytes` field of the status structure?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be `aio_error` doesn't modify anything - it simply checks and reports on the operation status (notice that is receives a `const` pointer). To resume a partial write you need to create a new I/O request and issue a new `aio_write(3)` with the remaining data, much like any regular write. If you can, have a look at Section 14.5 (page 509) of *Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment*, it has an example in the end of a program to translate a file using ROT-13 with asynchronous I/O.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Either way, consider whether this is really what you want to do. Asynchronous I/O is generally hard to get right, and most of the time, the additional complexity of the code complicates the design and makes it harder to debug.